# Can't refrain my script from grabbing unnecessary lines

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've written a script in python to get certain from a text container. I used `re` module to do the job. However, it is giving me unnecesary output along with the required ones.

How can I modify my expression to be stick to the lines I wanna grab?

This is my try:

```
import re

content = """
A Gross exaggeration,
-- Gross   5 90,630,08,
Gross      4 13,360,023,
      Gross      2 70,940,02,
Luke gross is an actor
"""
for item in re.finditer(r'Gross(?:[\d\s,]*)',content):
    print(item.group().strip())
```

Output I'm having:

```
Gross
Gross   5 90,630,08,
Gross      4 13,360,023,
Gross      2 70,940,02,
```

Output I wish to have:

```
Gross      4 13,360,023
Gross      2 70,940,02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the regex string to `r'(?:^\s*?)Gross[\d\s,]*?(?=,$)'` and added multiline flag ([online regex here](https://regex101.com/r/XQvBi3/1)):

```
import re

content = """
A Gross exaggeration,
-- Gross   5 90,630,08,
Gross      4 13,360,023,
      Gross      2 70,940,02,
Luke gross is an actor
"""

for item in re.finditer(r'(?:^\s*?)Gross[\d\s,]*?(?=,$)',content, flags=re.M):
    print(item.group().strip())
```

Output is:

```
Gross      4 13,360,023
Gross      2 70,940,02
```

Comment: Yep, It did it perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`^\s*Gross[\d ,]*(?=,)` Will capture what you want.

I just tacked on `^` to signal the start of the line, used `\s*` to indicate optional whitespace before "gross" and trimmed the `,` from the end. I also removed your `\s` from your character class because it worked with new lines. I replaced it with a blank space.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FZcPR8/1)